# How to add strata information to a genind

Tags: r

I have created a [genind](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adegenet/versions/1.0-0/topics/genind) object from a table containing SNPs information.

I need to insert population information into this genind.

I know which individuals (which are identified by numbers) should go into each population.

How do I pick the correct individuals and place them into separate populations?

Answer (score 3):

It's always helpful to make a reproducible example when asking a question.

First, loading the necessary library (pretty sure its adegenet)
`library(adegenet)`

Making some fake data by first getting a vector of alleles
`alleles <- paste0("0",1:4)`

Setting number of loci, individuals per population, and the number of populations

```
nloci <- 10
nind <- 10
npops <- 2
```

Using a for loop to make the fake dataset

```
i <- NULL
out <- NULL
for(i in 1:npops){
  #there are nind*nloci genotypes in each population
  #make a 
  gts <- replicate(n = nind*nloci,
                   expr = paste0(sample(x = alleles,size = 1,replace = T),
                                 sample(x = alleles,size = 1,replace = T)))
  gts <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = gts,
                              nrow = nind, ncol = nloci, byrow = T))
  #making generic locus colnames()
  colnames(gts) <- paste("locus_",1:nloci)
  out <- rbind(out,gts)
} #end of for loop
head(out)
```

Now converting that data.frame into a genind

```
obj <- df2genind(out, ploidy=2, ncode=2)
obj
```

Note that the row.names() are considered individual IDs

Now for setting the populations, note its empty right now

```
obj@pop
```

You just need a vector that represents the populations corresponding to each individual.

## Option 1

If your individual IDs are clustered by population (e.g. 1-10 are from pop1 and 11-20 are from pop2), then something like this should work

```
pops<- paste0("pop",1:npops)
```

Set the populations using that vector, make sure it's a factor

```
obj@pop <- as.factor(rep(pops,each=nind))
obj@pop
```

## Option 2

If the original data.frame (table) that contained your SNP information also contained population information, you could use that as your vector

e.g. If `out` looked like this

```
out$pops <- sample(x = pops,size = nrow(out),replace = T)
head(out)
```

Then do could use that column as your vector

```
obj@pop <- as.factor(out$pops)
obj@pop
```

## Option 3

Alternatively, if you had another table that enabled you to identify which individuals corresponded to which population, then you use that information. It assumes that the second table (data.frame) is the same number of rows as `out`

Here is an example second table

```
df <- data.frame(pops = rep(pops,each=nind),
                 id = sample(x = 1:nrow(out),size = nrow(out),replace = F))
head(df)
```

Note that the IDs are not in order, but they were in `out` and therefore are in the `obj`, so `df` needs to be ordered by `df$id`

```
df <- df[order(df$id),]
head(df)
```

After they are in the correct order

```
obj@pop <- as.factor(df$pops)
obj@pop
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for not including the data set or an example, I am new to all this! 
My problem is that the individual IDs are NOT clustered by populations.
For example, I have individual 001, 002, 003, .... 450
I know there are 2 populations.
But population 1 is composed of individuals 001, 006, 009, 150,....
Population 2 is composed of individuals 002, 003,004,005,007,008,010,....
That is where I get stuck.
Thanks again for your time!

Comment: No problem, glad I can help a fellow geneticist. Does the table containing the SNP info also have columns that identify IDs and population? Or do you have another table that has population and ID information in two different columns?

Comment: It is actually more complicated than that. 
I have SNP table with IDs as rows. I then performed a cluster analysis and an MDS to explore my data and saw that two distinct "populations" form. In both cases I was able to extract which IDs were in the two populations (they matched for both analyses). I now need a way to create a hierarchical level which I can insert into an amova in order to prove that there is population differentiation. I was thinking of creating two "populations" to insert into the genind object and then use that as my hierarchical level. But I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you again for your help, I was able to solve the problem!!

Comment: Hello, I only just saw these. Thank you @Sardimus for answering this. I have a couple of points of clarification:

1. In option 3, where you have several population factors in a data frame: *this is the strata that you can add to your genind object*. You would do so by using `strata(obj) <- df` and then set the population with `setPop(obj) <- ~pops`. 2. It's not a good idea to use the `@pop` accessor directly. It's best practice to add the population factor in the strata slot and then use `setPop()`. If you need to set the population temporarily, you can use `pop(obj) <- df$pops`