# define population level for PCA analysis in adegenet

Tags: r, pca, genetics

I want to perform a PCA analysis in adegenet starting from a genepop file without defined populations.
I imported the data like this:

```
datapop <- read.genepop('tous.gen', ncode=3, quiet = FALSE)
```

it works, and I can perform a PCA after scaling the data.
But I would like to plot the results / individuals on the PCA axis according to their population of origin using s.class. I have a vcf file with a three lettre code for each individual. I imported it in R:

```
pops_list <- read.csv('liste_pops.csv', header=FALSE)
```

but now how can I use it to define population levels in the genind object `datapop`?
I tried something likes this:

```
setPop(datapop, formula = NULL)
```

`setPop(datapop)` <- pops_list
but it doesn't work; even the first line doesn't work: I get this message:

```
"Erreur : formula must be a valid formula object."
```

And then how should I use it in s.class?
thanks
Didier

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example it is kind of hard to tell but perhaps you can find the solution to your problem here: [How to add strata information to a genind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415616/how-to-add-strata-information-to-a-genind)

Either way from your examples and given how the setPop method works, your line `setPop(datapop, formula = NULL)` would not work because you would not be defining anything. You would actually have to do:

```
setPop(datapop) <- pops_list
```

while also guaranteeing that pops_list is a factor with the appropriate format

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but the way to do this is to add `pops_list` as the `strata` and then use `setPop()` to select a certain column:

```
strata(datapop) <- pops_list
setPop(datapop) <- ~myPop # set the population to the column called "myPop" in the data frame
```